# Tablet-friendly interface and compatibility in Android development

Tags: android, user-interface, compatibility

I want to develop a new Android app. Design guidelines for Droid 3.0+ encourage the use of fragments to create a UI that better utilizes tablets' screen space. Also, from Droid 3.0+ I have read that a menu bar should exist on every activity that has a menu instead of using the plain old menu key

[image: Android UI menu bar]

These features are supported by SDK 11+, but I want to support SDK 8 as minimum SDK in order to achieve best market share (see [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)).

How can I achieve both of my objectives?

Comment: You could use one of the libraries out there, for example the `ActionBarSherlock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. Google provide [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for developing apps with using fragments and action bars with support of old android versions.
2. There is great tool [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: Actually, ActionBarSherlock provides Fragment support too.